# Remove a button of google docs viewer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im using the Google Docs Viewer to show a docx file that is hosted in my server.

The google doc viewer create somthing like this:

[image]

I need to remove the button in the red box when the docviewer is generated.

Im tryng with jquery and one of the clas of that buttom like this:

```
         $('.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-GSQQnc-LgbsSe').remove();
```

Where `ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-GSQQnc-LgbsSe` is a class of the button.

I try a lot and I'm running out of options.

Any idea for something that can resolve the problem?

Comment: you can't use css to hide it? e.g `.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-GSQQnc-LgbsSe{ display: none; }`

Comment: How can id add a css style to a element generated dinamically for the google docs viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this with jQuery. jQuery is easily overriden and unsafe, since the code is run on client-side.

I'm not sure how Google Docs Viewer works. If it works through an iFrame, you are out of luck. If it works through a PHP Class, you should modify the PHP to not show the button.

Comment: It works like this: I put this on the view <iframe id="iframe" class="doc" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://eisc.univalle.edu.co/materias/Material_Desarrollo_Software/CASOSUSO_A3.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe> and it show the doc in the page.

Comment: Then your are out of luck. You cannot change external iframes.

Comment: is free or comercial Google Docs Viewer?